# How to "forze" pluralize in EF Core Scaffold-Dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5, scaffolding, pluralize

When scaffolding an existing DB Model there are several table names that end with an `s`. Like `SaleOrderPos` beeing pos short for position.

I want to pluralize the DBSet but keep intanct the original table name.

EF creates a class called `SaleOrderPo`

`public virtual DbSet<SaleOrderPo> SaleOrderPos { get; set; }`

Rather than working with `Po` classes I prefer to use the option `-NoPluralize` when calling to Scaffold-DbContext:

`public virtual DbSet<SaleOrderPos> SaleOrderPos { get; set; }`

Is there a way to generate a class called `SaleOrderPos` and a DbSet called `SaleOrderPoss` or `SaleOrderPoses`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried "-UseDatabaseNames" option?

Comment: -UseDatabaseNames does not affect on the class name. It affects to entity property names, for example a column named t_column in DB, the property is TColumn. With -UseDatabaseNames it remains t_column.